# details on the ng-options expression

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-options

I have the below code which is used to drill down the tree structure from the model to the view in the dropdown. I am unable to understand the below expression:

`ng-options="classification for (classification, configs)  in filterData"`

Couple of doubts here.

1. Why is the classification dropdown points to `configs` for ng-model.
2. How can I get the selected classificaion (system_config or network_config) in my control?
3. On selecting the classification from the dropdown the configs are automatically getting filtered. How to get the selected config in my controller.

Plnkr link - [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/FulG886jdEGVFHzhks2k?p=preview)

The code for the view is as below:

```
<div class="m-b">
  <div class="form-group s-b" style="width: 150px;">
    <span>classification</span>
    <select class="form-control" id="classification" ng-model="configs" ng-options="classification for (classification, configs) in filterData" ng-change="handleClassification(criteria)" style="max-width:100%">    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group s-b" style="width: 150px;">
    <span>Config</span>
    <select id="config" ng-options="config for (config, attributes) in configs" class="form-control" ng-model="attributes" style="max-width:100%" ></select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group s-b" style="width: 150px;">
    <span>Attribute</span>
    <select id="attribute" class="form-control" ng-options="attribute for attribute in attributes"  ng-model="attribute" style="max-width:100%;" ng-change="handleAttrChange(attribute)"></select>
  </div>
</div>
```

The model is as below:

```
{
  "system_config": {
  "damask": [
    "umask"
  ],
  "fsuration": [
    "AUTOFSCK_DEF_CHECK"
    ],
    "hible": [
      "HIEFORMAT"
    ],
    "linux_status": [
    "SeLinuxStatus"
    ],
    "kl_version": [
      "KeelVersion"
    ],
    "ssh_parameters": [
      "Port",
      "Protocol"
    ],
    "network_parameter": [
      "kernel.shmmax",
      "kernel.sysrq"
    ],
      "snmp_community": [
      "rocommunity",
      "trapmmunity"
    ],
    "password_expiration_parameters": [
      "PASS_MAX_DAYS",
      "PASS_WARN_AGE"
    ]
  },
  "network_config": {
    "interface_configuration": [
      "ONBOOT"
    ],
    "networking_configuration": [
      "NETWORKING",
      "NETWORKING_IPV6",
      "NOZEROCONF"
    ],
    "interface_speed": [
      "InterfaceSpeed"
    ]
  }
}
```

Inside my controller on submit button click:

```
$scope.searchParams = function(){
   console.log($scope.configs);
 }
```

Please let me know since I am using the `ng-options` for the first time and getting confused.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, the select value will be stored in your ng-model variable. You're using this to filter your list and set the values for the next dropdown, thus not saving the selected option.

"classification for (classification, configs)  in filterData" means you're creating options for your select from the object filterData. The (classification,configs) part is a (key,value) of your objects. This means you're options will be the keys of the filterData object and the results you'll be storing in configs (which also is your ng-model) the value of the object keys. You can find more information about it [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

To access the select values you could use HTML

```
 $("#classification")[0].options[$("#classification")[0].selectedIndex].innerText;
```

or you can use the ng-change directive to call a function that sets the selected value. Change your ng-change to  ng-change="handleClassification(configs)" instead of "criteria" and then add to your script

```
$scope.handleClassification = function(cfg){
    $scope.myConfig = cfg;
}
```

Comment: I printed the $scope.configs in the controller after submitting the submit button. When I print the values of $scope.configs, I get the list of key value pairs but not the selected classification, selected config, selected attribute. Please let me know how to get the selected values from the dropdown. Updated the question and plunker for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I followed the approach to handle it based on `ng-change` and implemented but there is one more use case. When I add one more set of dropdowns I am not able to set the scope for each items seperately. Can you let me know how to fix this.

Comment: Can you please update your plunker? If just add one more "level" of data to your dataFilter and follow the same approach as before you should be able to.

Comment: And maybe update your original question so we don't go into sub-questions and answers on comments...